# How to make php 5 on the site so that after paying on the payment system's website and returning back to the site, the user's session is not saved?

Tags: cookies

I need that after paying on the payment system's website and returning back to the php 5 site, the user's session is not saved.

I tried to implement this through the site and server settings. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

Decision:

1. Make a link in the code of the payment settings of the SuccessURL site after making the payment ("Return to the site") to the exit button from the personal account on the site - /login/?out.
2. Make the site code so that when you exit your personal account, there is a transition to log in to your personal account - /login/